# How to avoid QListWidget list item being reset when adding new item?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I have a GUI with a QListWidget that starts with no entries. Entries are added using an "add" button. The problem I have is that when you edit the text of a list item, if you click the add button again before hitting enter or clicking away, the text you enter gets erased (see gif for reference)

[image: screenshot]

Also, another gif to show that the code is otherwise working:

[image: screenshot]

The problem is that it doesn't save what you are typing with each keystroke. It instead waits until you are finished and have changed the selection or pressed enter.

Can anyone suggest a way to fix this?

**Code:**

I have the following signals declared in the init function of my GUI class:

```
self.w_client_list.itemChanged.connect(self.edit_client_name)
self.w_client_list.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.switching_clients)
self.b_add_client.clicked.connect(self.add_client)
```

These are the Slot functions that signals are connected to:

```
    def get_index(self):
        """Gets index number of selected client for client details functions"""
        for i in range(self.w_client_list.count()):
            if self.w_client_list.item(i).isSelected():
                index = i
                return index
        index = None
        return index

    @Slot()
    def switching_clients(self):
        index = self.get_index()
        if index == None:
            self.l_email.clear()
            self.c_main_email.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
            self.c_secondary_email.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
            self.w_phone.clear()
            self.l_preferred_name.clear()
            self.w_title.setCurrentText('Mr')
        else:
            # Email
            self.l_email.setText(self.client.individual[index]['email'][0])
            self.c_main_email.setChecked(self.client.individual[index]['email'][1])
            self.c_secondary_email.setChecked(self.client.individual[index]['email'][2])
            # Phone
            self.update_phone_list()
            # Preferred Name
            self.l_preferred_name.setText(self.client.individual[index]['preferred_name'])
            # Title
            self.w_title.setCurrentText(self.client.individual[index]['title'])

    @Slot()
    def edit_client_name(self):
        index = self.get_index()
        self.client.individual[index]['full_name'] = self.w_client_list.item(index).text().strip()
        self.switching_clients()

    @Slot()
    def add_client(self):
        self.client.individual.append({'title': 'Mr', 'first_name': '', 'middle_name': '', 'last_name': '',
                                        'full_name': 'Enter full name',
                                        'preferred_name': '', 'salutation': '', 'postal_salutation': '',
                                        'email': ['', 0, 0], 'address': [], 'phone': [],
                                        'preferred_name_connected': True})
        self.update_client_list()  # Updates the client form to show new address row

    def update_client_list(self):
        self.w_client_list.clear()
        client_list = []
        for client in self.client.individual:
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
            item.setText(client['full_name'])
            item.setFlags(
                QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            self.w_client_list.addItem(item)
        item.setSelected(True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by [setting the focus policy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop) of the buttons to `NoFocus`. This allows the item-editor to stay open when the buttons are clicked (because they won't steal the focus). The list-widget's [isPersistentEditorOpen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#isPersistentEditorOpen) method can then be used to prevent unwanted operations whilst the user is still editing.

**UPDATE**:

If you want to commit the current edit when adding a new item, you can just call `setFocus` on the list-widget (since the button doesn't steal the focus). This also means there's no longer any need to check whether the item-editor is open as suggested above.

---

Here is a working demo based on your code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Client:
    individual = []

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.client = Client()
        self.b_add_client = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Add')
        self.b_add_client.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.w_client_list = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.w_client_list)
        layout.addWidget(self.b_add_client)
        self.w_client_list.itemChanged.connect(self.edit_client_name)
        self.b_add_client.clicked.connect(self.add_client)

    def get_index(self):
        selection = self.w_client_list.selectedItems()
        if selection:
            return self.w_client_list.indexFromItem(selection[0]).row()

    def switching_clients(self):
        pass

    def edit_client_name(self):
        index = self.get_index()
        if index is not None:
            text = self.w_client_list.item(index).text().strip()
            if text:
                self.client.individual[index]['full_name'] = text
        self.switching_clients()

    def add_client(self):
        self.w_client_list.setFocus()
        self.client.individual.append({
            'title': 'Mr', 'first_name': '', 'middle_name': '',
            'last_name': '', 'full_name': 'Enter full name',
            'preferred_name': '', 'salutation': '',
            'postal_salutation': '', 'email': ['', 0, 0],
            'address': [], 'phone': [],
            'preferred_name_connected': True,
            })
        self.update_client_list()

    def update_client_list(self):
        if len(self.client.individual):
            self.w_client_list.clear()
            for client in self.client.individual:
                item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
                item.setText(client['full_name'])
                item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
                self.w_client_list.addItem(item)
            item.setSelected(True)
            self.w_client_list.editItem(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 300, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks ekhumoro. This is great but I would ideally like it if clicking the "add" button would commit the change if the user is editing. I have tried to implement this by changing focus when the "add" button is clicked but I think it would require multithreading to work because otherwise it will continue to add the new list item and refresh the list before the itemChanged signal/slot is triggered. Using multithreading to fix this seems messy, so I'm hoping there's a more obvious way.

Comment: You *cannot* alter a Qt GUI in multiple threads. You *have* to stay in one thread when you do GUI operations.

Comment: @Hol3yMol3y I have updated my answer so that it works in the way you want. There is no need for multi-threading, or any other such complications.

Comment: Excellent! That works perfectly and is such a simple solution. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is that when the user clicks "add", the program first verifies if the entry was changed by comparing the "old" string.
and the new one. if it was, it will save the new string and set it to the widget. Otherwise it will simply add the new entry. I hope this can lead you to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The current behavior is the expected behavior.

You correctly identified the culprit: Editing changes need to be commited by the user, and interrupting the editing process will cancel it. If you would like changes to be applied instantly, you need a custom delegate that implements your alternate behavior. (See [this example in Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-stardelegate-example.html) for how custom delegates work).

Note though that changing elementary UI behavior like this is strongly disregarded. Your app will look like any other app, but subtly behave differently to the rest. In the UI world, generally *consistency* is king. Customizing such behavior can also have unforseen side effects, especially if you target multiple platforms. And it is a lot of extra code that needs to be maintained.

Comment: Thanks ypnos. Yes - I'm not really interested in using a custom delegate, and I don't mind that the changes aren't committed with each keystroke. However, I would like it  if clicking the "add" button would commit the change to the list item if the user is in the middle of editing it. I have commented on my attempt at this above under ekhumoros answer.

Comment: Even more obscure, and frankly, only possible with a delegate that receives a custom signal to commit, which you can trigger before the focus changes by tracking focus events yourself... All in all nothing pleasurable to do.

Comment: @ypnos Actually, it's a lot simpler than that. Once the button can no longer receive focus, it becomes possible to explicitly set focus on the list-widget, which will in turn commit the data in the item-editor (if one's open). It would also be possible to hook into the item-delegate to force it to commit its data, but I don't think it's necessary in this particular case.

Comment: Interesting! Great approach!